# Unable to get all the names from a table

Tags: python, python-3.x, web-scraping

I've created a script in python to get all the names out of a table from a webpage. The names within that table are available in the page source so they are `static content`. However, when I try with my following script, I get few of them (upto `2012 Topps Heritage Run`) whereas the list are many more.

[Site address](https://www.psacard.com/psasetregistry/baseball/company-sets/16)

***How can I get all the names from the table under `Company Sets` header using requests?***

I've tried with so far:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = "https://www.psacard.com/psasetregistry/baseball/company-sets/16"

res = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(res.text,"lxml")
for item in soup.select(".dataTable tr td a[href*='/baseball/company-sets/']"):
    print(item.text)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you try the following:

```
print([inner_tag.find('a').text for inner_tag in soup.findAll('table')[0].findAll('td') if inner_tag.find('a')])
```

Explanation:

- Actually there are two tables in the page, and your code was extracting values from both the tables. That's the reason why you were getting the last value 2012.
- The above code extracts the text only from the first table named `Company Sets`

Answer (score 0):

You could combine requests with pandas read_html

```
import pandas as pd
import requests
url = 'https://www.psacard.com/psasetregistry/baseball/company-sets/16'
headers = {'User-Agent' : 'Mozilla/5.0'}
r= requests.get(url, headers= headers)
tables = pd.read_html(r.content)
df = tables[0]
df.drop(df.index[[0]], inplace = True)
print(df)
```